# How to download maven dpendencies to a specific folder

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have following as dependencies in pom.xml file,

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I want to save those downloaded jar files to a directory which I specified. What is the exact way?

Comment: Why? Are you trying to create a folder of project dependencies? There's a task for that.

Comment: maybe have a look here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html

Comment: Mave automatically download dependency jars to your local maven repository. You can change the default location by specifying <localRepository> in ../your-profile/.m2/settings.xml.

Comment: Thanks Olamy, You solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the build POM section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>[your.dep.group.id]</groupId>
                        <artifactId>[your.dep.artifact.id]</artifactId>
                        <version>[your.dep.version]</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>[your.output.dir]</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```